# This error keeps appearing in my code and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8, ios10

I'm making an ios game app in Xcode 8 using swift 3 and I keep getting an error that says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (codeEXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" and a console message that says fatal error: "Index out of range (lldb)". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's the section of code with the error. I get it on the line that says 'let nodeB = cableSegments[i]'

```
for i in 1..<length {
        let nodeA = cableSegments[i - 1]
        let nodeB = cableSegments[i]
        let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody!, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody!,
                                            anchor: CGPoint(x: nodeA.frame.midX, y: nodeA.frame.minY))

        scene.physicsWorld.add(joint)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "out of range" error is common in many programming languages. It indicates to you that the loop is trying to access a position in the array that is out of the array range.

Per your code above it's not possible to figure out where are you obtaining the `length` value, but it should be the array length.

May the code below could work:

```
var counter = 0

for i in 0..<cableSegments.count {

    counter += 1

    if counter == cableSegments.count {
        break
    }

    let nodeA = cableSegments[i]
    let nodeB = cableSegments[i + 1]
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody!, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody!,
                                        anchor: CGPoint(x: nodeA.frame.midX, y: nodeA.frame.minY))

    scene.physicsWorld.add(joint)
}
```

Comment: Thx! That fixed it!